# Pandas data frame has numbers & string. Need to round off to 2 decimal places

Tags: python, pandas, rounding

The below data frame needs to be rounded to 2 decimal places.

Code below:

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 import pandas.io.formats.excel

 df1= pd.read_excel(C:\Users\Excel\Data.xlsx)

 df1.round(2)

 display(df1)
```

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Company 1 | 10.256 | USD |
| Company 2 | 11.25 | USD |
| Company 3 | 12.34456 | USD |
| Company 4 | 23.432 | USD |

I've tried these 4 methods, but no luck. It's displaying the data frame as it is without rounding off to 2 decimal places:

1. df.round(2)
2. df1[['B']] = df1[['B']].round(decimals = 2)
3. np.round(df1, decimals=2)
4. df.round({ "B":2})

Desired Output:
| A        |    B   |        C |
| ----     |----    | ---      |
|Company 1 |  10.25 |      USD
|Company 2 |  11.25 |      USD
|Company 3 |  12.34 |      USD
|Company 4 |  23.43 |      USD

PS: The source data file for column B within Excel is general.

Answer (score 0):

You need assign back:

```
df1 = df1.round(2)
print (df1)
           A      B    C
0  Company 1  10.26  USD
1  Company 2  11.25  USD
2  Company 3  12.34  USD
3  Company 4  23.43  USD
```